# Flutter display nearby users by Latitude and Longitude from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder, geofirestore

I have 2 apps that I am connecting together, and they work like this: it's similar to a food delivery, where I have one Restaurant app, which will add the restaurant location, and I am storing this location by Latitude and Longitude on my Firebase Collection for Restaurant. On the other App, the "eater" app, I want to display the nearby Restaurant docs from Firestore (the docs include name, image and description for now).

With the "eater" app, I can already store their current location. The only thing that I am trying to do, shows the nearby Restaurants.

**Here is my showNearbyCompanies() function**

```
Stream showNearbyCompanies() async* {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();

    GeoFirePoint point =
        geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);

    double distance = 30;

    double lat = 0.023323826086956514;
    double lon = 0.02926080000000002776;

    double lowerLat = point.latitude - (lat * distance);
    double lowerLon = point.longitude - (lon * distance);

    double greaterLat = point.latitude + (lat * distance);
    double greaterLon = point.longitude + (lon * distance);

    GeoPoint lesserGeoPoint = GeoPoint(lowerLat, lowerLon);
    GeoPoint greaterGeoPoint = GeoPoint(greaterLat, greaterLon);

    Query query = _firebaseFirestore
        .collection("Companies")
        .where("location", isGreaterThan: lesserGeoPoint)
        .where("location", isLessThan: greaterGeoPoint);

    yield query;
  }

**//This is another example instead of query**


showNearbyCompanies() async {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();

    GeoFirePoint point =
        geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);

    double distance = 30;

    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: _firebaseFirestore.collection("Companies"))
        .within(center: point, radius: distance, field: 'location');

    stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
      // print(stream.length);
      print('Here');
      print(documentList[0].data());
    });
  }
```

And I need to display it here, this is what I am trying to do, but obviously does not work because Query is not a string, but that is the problem I can't solve:

**Code**

```
Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: showNearbyCompanies(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text("Loading");
                }
                return Text(snapshot.data); // this needs to be the query, I don't know how to do
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: can you post the output of query yielded by showNearbyCompanies please ?

Comment: How do I do that exactly? I thought that was my problem, I don't know a widget to yield it... I was using a Text widget but it returns the error Query is not a type of String obviously...

Comment: Yeah, it returns " instance of " Query"" haha

Comment: can you try print `query` before yielding it ? i suppose that `query` is a map or a list of maps.

Comment: Yeah, print(query) returns me Instance of Query

Comment: does the Query class expose a `snapshots` method ?

Comment: Yeah, Should I try yield query.snapshots()?

Comment: Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot>' printing query.snapshots();

Comment: I've updated my code with the GeoFlutterFire example of using a stream, if it makes more sense to you